# Inserting data based on hour and day of the week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a set of hourly data taken from 07-Feb-19 to 17-Feb-19:

```
                             t     v_amm     v_alc     v_no2
0    2019-02-07 08:00:00+00:00  0.320000  0.344000  1.612000
1    2019-02-07 09:00:00+00:00  0.322889  0.391778  1.580889
2    2019-02-07 10:00:00+00:00  0.209375  0.325208  2.371250
...
251  2019-02-17 19:00:00+00:00  1.082041  0.652041  0.967143
252  2019-02-17 20:00:00+00:00  0.936923  0.598654  1.048077
253  2019-02-17 21:00:00+00:00  0.652553  0.499574  1.184894
```

and another similar set of hourly data taken from 01-Mar-19 to 11-Mar-19:

```
                            t     v_amm     v_alc     v_no2
0   2019-03-01 00:00:00+00:00  0.428222  0.384444  1.288222
1   2019-03-01 01:00:00+00:00  0.398600  0.359600  1.325800
2   2019-03-01 02:00:00+00:00  0.365682  0.352273  1.360000
...
244 2019-03-11 04:00:00+00:00  0.444048  0.415238  1.265000
245 2019-03-11 05:00:00+00:00  0.590698  0.591395  1.156977
246 2019-03-11 06:00:00+00:00  0.497872  0.465319  1.228298
```

However, there is **no data available between 17-Feb-19 and 01-Mar-19**.
Hence, I'd like to insert the following data (grouped by day of the week and the hour) into the missing date and times:

```
                     v_amm     v_alc     v_no2
day_of_week hour                              
0           0     0.432222  0.351111  1.258889
            1     0.371026  0.324359  1.323333
            2     0.371026  0.324359  1.323333
            3     0.250000  0.285000  1.510000
            4     0.220000  0.274500  1.616500
            5     0.195263  0.264211  1.666053
...
6           18    0.919158  0.557793  1.018703
            19    1.065220  0.599320  0.965771
            20    0.896227  0.543689  1.045634
            21    0.648488  0.469210  1.187928
            22    0.592200  0.417200  1.154400
            23    0.485918  0.366531  1.215918
```

Does anyone know how to obtain this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

First, generate the missing indexes then concatenate dataframes.

```
new_index = pd.date_range(start='2019-02-17', end='2019-03-01', freq='H')
new_df = pd.DataFrame([new_index], index=['t']).T
new_df['day_of_week'] = [z.weekday() for z in new_index]
new_df['hour'] = [z.hour for z in new_index]
new_df = new_df.merge(<your_df>, on=['day_of_week', 'hour']), how='left')
new_df = new_df.drop(['day_of_week', 'hour'], axis=1)
filled_df = pd.concat([<df1>, new_df, <df2>], axis=0)
```